# SQL ROUND function for a number with 3 decimal points to nearest 50th 100th

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Can someone help to get output as shown below

```
1.012 ->  1.050
1.835 ->  1.850
1.676 ->  1.700
1.123 ->  1.150
1.999 ->  2.000
5.000 ->  5.000
9.450 ->  9.450
```

Comment: wouldn't the "nearest 50" of `1.012` be `1.000`? or do you always want to round up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the ceiling of the the division of your number and 0.05 and multiply with 0.05 again.

```
...
ceiling(nmuloc / 0.05) * 0.05
...
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8cab28a376d6313025180cf4f514189e)